# Convert RTF string to XAML string

Tags: c#, xaml, rtf

What is the most efficient way to convert an RTF string to a XAML string in C#? I'd like to use `System.Windows.Documents.XamlRtfConverter.ConvertRtfToXaml(string rtfContent)` but unfortunately that class is internal.

Comment: what is a `Xaml string` ?

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo Read the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xaml/info)

Comment: I know that, But the `XAML string` related to `RTF string` is strange to me...

Comment: Please leave comments regarding down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go from an RTF string to a XAML string but you lose images:

```
 var rtf = File.ReadAllText(rtfFileName);
 var doc = new FlowDocument();
 var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
 using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf)))
 {
    range.Load(inputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       range.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.Xaml);
       outputStream.Position = 0;
       using (var xamlStream = new StreamReader(outputStream))
       {
          var xaml = xamlStream.ReadToEnd();
          File.WriteAllText(xamlFileName, xaml);
       }
    }
 }
```

To preserve images you have to go from an RTF string to a XAML package:

```
 var rtf = File.ReadAllText(rtfFileName);
 var doc = new FlowDocument();
 var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
 using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf)))
 {
    range.Load(inputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(xamlFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
       range.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use System.Reflection to invoke internal method XamlRtfConverter in System.Windows.Documents (needs reference to PresentationFramework.dll).
It works for thousands of conversions in Parallel.ForEach() without memory crashes (in contrast to conversion via RichTextBox).

```
    private static string ConvertRtfToXaml(string rtfContent)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Windows.FrameworkElement));
        var xamlRtfConverterType = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Documents.XamlRtfConverter");
        var xamlRtfConverter = Activator.CreateInstance(xamlRtfConverterType, true);
        var convertRtfToXaml = xamlRtfConverterType.GetMethod("ConvertRtfToXaml", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var xamlContent = (string)convertRtfToXaml.Invoke(xamlRtfConverter, new object[] { rtfContent });
        return xamlContent;
    }
```