# Convert RTF to XAML in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, rtf

I have a RichEditBox that I want to convert to a RichTextBlock. To do that, I need to convert the RTF string to an XAML string. Is it possible to do that? Are there any NuGet packages for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert RTF string to XAML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123907/convert-rtf-string-to-xaml-string)

Comment: @marsh-wiggle No, because I'm on UWP

Answer (score 0):

One possible way seems to be converting the RTF to HTML first and then from HTML to XAML

The [RtfPipe library on GitHub](https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe) has a 'ToHtml' method

```
using RtfPipe;

string htmlString = Rtf.ToHtml(rtfString);
```

Then you may use a [HtmlToXamlConverter](https://github.com/stimulant/SocialStream/blob/master/XAMLConverter/HtmlToXamlConverter.cs) to get your XAML string

```
string xamlFlowDocument = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(htmlString, true);
```

Comment: I did this already, and it works, but some formatting is lost in the process